# Routing to an error channel if fault is thrown in outbound gateway in DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following Spring Integration JAva DSL code:

```
    return flow -> flow.channel(INPUT_CHANNEL)
            .transform(customMapper, "mapFrom")
            .enrichHeaders(polarisPreCompSoapActionHeader())
            .route("headers.key",
                    subflowMapping -> subflowMapping
                            .subFlowMapping("value1", subflow -> subflow
                                    .handle(webserviceOutboundGateway,
                                            e -> e.advice(skipAdvice()))
                            )
            )
            .channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL);

@Bean
public Advice skipAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setFailureChannel(errorChannel());
    return advice;
}
```

The `webserviceOutboundGateway` is created as a bean of `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`.

What I am trying to achieve is to route the error message to the error channel when a SOAP fault arrives. I thought that I can add an advice to the handler and this advice should be an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` where I can set the failure channel. So whenever an error is thrown in the outbound gateway then the error message will be forwarded to the error channel.

Then problem is that now the gateway throw an exception and the flow stops

```
2020-05-20 22:21:48,161 INFO  com.acme.Timing Thread=qtp14486859-12 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d REQUEST COMPLETE : time[39]ms  message[ProcessTran] endpoint[http://localhost:8081/system-integration-service/service]
2020-05-20 22:21:48,161 DEBUG org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher$Gateway Thread=qtp14486859-12 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: error occurred in message handler [webserviceOutboundGateway]; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
2020-05-20 22:21:48,162 DEBUG org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway Thread=qtp14486859-12 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: error occurred in message handler [webserviceOutboundGateway]; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
2020-05-20 22:21:48,167 ERROR com.acme.webservice.OrchestrationServiceEndpoint Thread=qtp14486859-12 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d Error
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:87)
        at com.acme.webservice.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:60)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:188)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:194)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
```

Any advice / help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks,
V.

---

UPDATE1

I set the trapExecution to false, added the advice to the gateway directly and I had to use `setOnFailureExpressionString` otherwise the flow was hanging. So how it looks now as follows:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway webserviceOutboundGateway(...) {
    MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = new ...;
    gateway.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(skipAdvice()));
    return gateway;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("skipCallChannel")
private MessageChannel skipCallChannel;

@Bean
public Advice skipAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setFailureChannel(endChannel);
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
2020-05-21 14:45:13,921 DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler Thread=qtp14486859-19 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler@cdf55 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=uk.co.acme._2009._03.ProcessTran@1759824, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1ddbf77, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1ddbf77, header.cqs.model=com.acme.model.FlowModel@cc006f, ws_soapAction=http://www.acme.co.uk/XRTEService/2009/03/ProcessTran, id=59e305ee-1672-d5ba-db4b-672198f25ab8, timestamp=1590068713891}], headers={id=14aeb6ed-77af-52bf-6b53-72bc0a4bb5c1, timestamp=1590068713921}]
2020-05-21 14:45:13,922 DEBUG org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher$Gateway Thread=qtp14486859-19 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
2020-05-21 14:45:13,922 DEBUG org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway Thread=qtp14486859-19 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
2020-05-21 14:45:13,927 ERROR com.acme.webservice.OrchestrationServiceEndpoint Thread=qtp14486859-19 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d Error
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.evaluateFailureExpression(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:271)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.doInvoke(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:221)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:112)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:194)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
```

I presume I have to add channel for successful execution but I don't want to do that as it is already defined in the flow where the handler is (see `.channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL)`). Can I set only the fault channel in the advice?
Thanks!

---

UPDATE2

I did what Gary recommended (i.e. added an error channel to the upstream flow) and the error message is delivered now to the error channel. However now I have another problem which vaguely relates to my original problem. So now I have the following exception:

```
2020-05-22 10:10:48,023 ERROR com.acme.webservice.OrchestrationServiceEndpoint Thread=qtp14486859-13 MDC=16d7cc4c-c9da-449b-8bfa-504e6d81185d Error
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred in error-handling flow; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'enrich.acmeRequest.output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=uk.co.acme.payload.request._2017._06.Message@4a5e6c, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@19d4520, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@19d4520, ws_soapAction=http://www.acme.co.uk/XRTEService/ProcessTran, id=902bd270-89d8-62e9-b00f-b69399241bd1, timestamp=1590138648017}], ...}]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher$Gateway.sendAndReceiveMessage(ContentEnricher.java:481)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher.handleRequestMessage(ContentEnricher.java:383)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
```

In the main flow I have the following:

```
    return flow -> flow.channel(ORCH_REQUEST_INPUT)
            .<HomeRequest, HomeModel>transform(requestToModelTransformer)
            ...
            // 
            .enrich(this::acmePreCompRequestEnricher)
            .enrich(this::acmePreCompEnricher)
            .handle(this.acmePreCompResponseValidator())
            // 
            .enrich(this::mlRequestEnricher)
            .enrich(this::mlEnricher)
            // 
            .enrich(this::acmeRequestEnricher)
            .enrich(this::acmeEnricher)
            ...
```

The SOAP fault is thrown in `acmePreCompEnricher` where the outbound gateway is used. The error channel is set to `skip.ml.input` then I have to following flow which handles the fault:

```
    return flow -> flow.channel("skip.ml.input")
            .transform(ErrorMessage.class, (ErrorMessage m) -> {
                        Message originalMessage = ((MessageHandlingException)m.getPayload()).getFailedMessage();
                        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(originalMessage.getHeaders().get(HEADER_CQS_MODEL, HomeQuoteModel.class))
                                .copyHeaders(originalMessage.getHeaders())
                                .build();
                    })
            .channel("enrich.acmeRequest.output");
```

The `enrich.acmeRequest.output` channel is the reply channel of `acmeRequestEnricher`. My intention is if there is no error then execute all the tasks in the flow but if there is a SOAP fault in `acmePreCompEnricher` then skip the `mlRequestEnricher` and `mlEnricher` and go straight to `acmeRequestEnricher`.
I presume the problem is that in the faul scenario the SI cannot see what subscribed to the channel of `acmeRequestEnricher`...? What can I do in this case?

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace; truncation loses too much information.

Comment: I added a longer stack trace, please let me know if it is enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gary Russell recommended in one of his comments I set an error channel in the upstream flow (see UPDATE2).

Answer (score 0):

See this method on the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
/**
 * If true, any exception will be caught and null returned.
 * Default false.
 * @param trapException true to trap Exceptions.
 */
public void setTrapException(boolean trapException) {
```

So, set it to `true` to avoid exception rethrowing.

See more in Docs, too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

**UPPDATE**

Since everything works but advice, it looks like a bug in the obsolete Java DSL project. Please, consider to inject your `skipAdvice` into the `webserviceOutboundGateway` directly. It has a respective setter:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link Advice}s to proxy a {@link #handleRequestMessage(Message)} method.
 * @param adviceChain the list of {@link Advice}s to use.
 */
public void setAdviceChain(List<Advice> adviceChain) {
```

**UPDATE2**

OK. Looks like you need to send a reply back, after processing that SOAP error.
So, you probably don't need that `failureChannel` configuration. The expression you have so far should be enough to trap an exception and send some plain string back to the gateway on top as a reply.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried it but the output is the same unfortunately.

Comment: The channel is an input channel of another IntegrationFlow where I will audit the SOAP fault and afterwards the flow will continue. So the main purpose of the error handling is not to terminate the flow but carry on.

Comment: OK. So, call that channel like `soapErrorChannel`, but not as a global one. Probably the second `LoggingHandler` is subscribed to your channel for now...

Comment: The stack trace doesn't match the configuration; there is no advice chain involved; line 109 means the `handleRequestMessage` is called directly (no advice). Looks like 5.0.x.

Comment: Thanks Gary for having a look! CAn you confirm that in the code above I did the right thing? I added the advice to the handler of `webserviceOutboundGateway`. Should anything else be configured to make the advice work?

Comment: Yes, it is correct; but there is definitely no advice chain configured. Perhaps you have another bean definition that's overriding this one.

Comment: Can you show what version you are using; looks like it might be 4.3.x (something) according to the line numbers, with the stand-alone DSL (the DSL was merged into core in 5.x). 4.3 will go out of support at the end of the year.

Comment: That's correct, I am using 4.3.12. It is a legacy code so it cannot be upgraded I am afraid. I dont insist on the advice, any other solution can be as brilliant. Is there anything else I can use other than `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can inject that advice directly into your `webserviceOutboundGateway` bean. There is a respective bean

Comment: Depending on what is upstream of INPUT_CHANNEL, you could simply put the error channel on whatever starts the flow and catch it there.

Comment: And you should at least upgrade to the current 4.3.21 version.

Comment: That's 4.3.22; the project page was out od date.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell and Artem, I updated the original question, would you please be so kind to have a look what goes wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you do on that `endChannel`, please? The exception talks exactly about this one `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.evaluateFailureExpression(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:271)`, not a success

Comment: I am still in "developing mode" which means that at the moment  in the advice I forward the error message to the last channel of the flow. I just want to see if the advice works. Can it be that the problem is what I mentioned in the UPDATE1 part?

Comment: I don't know why the `org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available` is thrown as I specify an error channel and it is an existing one.

Comment: Right. And what is your flow on that `endChannel`, please?

Comment: There is no flow for the channel, that is the end of the main flow, see `@Bean  public IntegrationFlow process() {return flow -> flow.channel("start_channel").  ...  .channel("end_channel"); }`. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: See UPDATEs in my answer.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell and Artem, I have some progression but bumped into the next problem... Could you please check the UPDATE2 part in my original question? Thanks!

Comment: Or shall I create a separate SO question for this?

Comment: Can it be a problem that I am using a DirectChannel and it has already one sender and one receiver so from the error channel I cannot send the message there as it would be a new sender? Should I use a different type of channel?

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than extending the commentary on this one.